# Android | Native Browser | HTML5 | Datepicker tabindex does not work

Tags: android, html, datepicker

I am adding a date input to the page. It has a tab index of 2. It is ignored every time I click the next/ prev buttons.

This only happens on the native Android Browser. It is fine on iOS/ Chrome.

https://jsfiddle.net/ozjyag0L/10/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
  <input id="one" tabindex="1" value='1' />
  <input id="two" tabindex="2" type="date" />
  <input id="three" tabindex="3" value='3' />
  <input id="four" tabindex="4" value='4' />
</div>
```

Has anybody run into this issue and know how to fix it?

**NATIVE BROWSERS TESTED:**

Gingerbread
Kitkat (Samsung Galaxy S5)

Cheers!

Comment: Be more specific with native browser-  there are at least a half dozen.  OEMs frequently install their own browser instead.

Comment: Sorry mate. I have tested it on Gingerbread and Kitkat (Samsung Galaxy S5 - which I know uses its own native browser).